# Backup windows 7 boot loader

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, bootloader

I have windows 7 ultimate and planning to install **ubuntu** as second OS.

Is there any way by which I can backup my windows 7 ultimate boot loader so that whenever I want to get rid-off ubuntu just run that backup and format the drive in which ubuntu was installed and it's over.

by running that backup only boot loader should to changed. All the drives must not be affected.

Comment: I would use a Gnu+Linux live CD, then copy it with `dd`. Best to ask on Ubuntu or Unix forum to get how to do this safely.

Comment: Could you not just do a Startup Repair in Windows to re-build the boot loader data? DD is an excellent program that can do what you're after so if you're game then give it a try...

Comment: @BigChris thanks. I am gonna try DD. whats full name of DD?

Comment: If I could write only two characters here, I woudl love to... but I have to write more... The full name of dd is dd. ;)

Comment: Here is the wikipedia article on [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)) and the [dd manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to.
The command `bootsect /nt60` will quickly restore your bootloader.

Procceed as follows:

-Boot from your Windows Disc
-Go to the command prompt ('rapair your computer')
-enter: `bootsect /nt60 sys`
-enter: `bootrec /fixmbr`

Now reboot your pc and you should get straight to windows. From there, using your favourite partition editor, delete your linux partitions and resize your windows partitions to maximum size.

Comment: Well, technically it will only restore the boot sector. That’s enough because the bootloader itself won’t be touched, otherwise Windows wouldn’t boot at all, even when selected in GRUB.

Comment: It worked I used two commands on the command prompt after booting windows disk **bootrec /fixboot** and **bootrec /fixmbr**.